# How to perform motion compensation on two jpeg pictures?

Tags: python, c++, jpeg, h.264, hevc

Now I have several JPEG images taken in a burst, and I want to use motion compensation technology on them to reduce the difference between them.Is there any ready-made code that can be used, preferably C++ or python.

Comment: Why is H.264 tagged? Also your **expected result** is unclear. _"I want to use motion compensation technology on them [jpegs] to reduce the difference between them"_ makes no sense without further explanation. What should be achieved after motion compensating two jpegs to "reduce them"? **PS:** They are down-voting your question because it's [asking for recommendation of tools/code which is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

1. Decompress your JPEG still images
2. Re-compress your JPEGs into AVC (H.264) or HEVC (H.265)
3. Stick the resulting stream into a MP4 or MOV container

You can do this with FFMPEG on the command line, use FFMPEG's C-API, find a FFMPEG Python wrapper.

Or you could use libJPEG (C-API) to decompress than use x264 (C-API) to make AVC.

Comment: Thank you. Is this solution lossless? I don't want to introduce any loss.

Comment: There is something like truly lossless. But in reality it is about visually lossless 

The question is more about: 'Can you see the loss?'
Increase the quality of your H.264 so you don't see the loos.